# How to Create New Folder in Windows XP and Add a new text file in the folder

Tags: windows-xp, file-management, shell-extensions

I want new folders created on my Windows XP machine to automatically contain a text file.

Is there a way to perhaps add a new context menu on the right click menu which runs some sort of bat file?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to write your own 'Create New Folder' context menu item for Windows Explorer.  You'd have to dig into the registry to add the appropriate entry to your context menus.

Here's the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753589(VS.85).aspx) for adding such menu items.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add your `BAT` file to the `SendTo` folder in your user profile - i.e. `%USERPROFILE%\SendTo`.  This will add an entry to the Send To menu with the same name as the batch file.

The filename of the item you right-clicked on is passed to the batch file as the first argument.

(In Windows 7 it's not `%USERPROFILE%\SendTo` - it's `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo`)